# Python file exercise issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following a tutorial in a textbook, "Starting out with python 2nd edition" and I'm getting a traceback with this exercise in IDLE 3.2. I can't seem to figure out the issue, it allows me to input the number of sales then only 1 sales amount it the echos "Data written to sales.txt." then displays the prompt for day 2 but any amount entered causes a traceback:

line 118, in main
   sales_file.write(str(sales) + '\n')
   ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Code:

```
def main():

     num_days = int(input('For how many days do ' + \
                          'you have sales? '))

     sales_file = open('sales.txt', 'w')


     for count in range(1, num_days + 1):
         sales = float(input('Enter the sales for day #' + \
                             str(count) + ': '))
         sales_file.write(str(sales) + '\n')
         sales_file.close()
         print('Data written to sales.txt.')

main()
```

Comment: Note that you do not need ` + \ ` to do string concatenation: it is best to just remove it. In fact, consecutive string literals are automatically concatenated by Python: `'Example ' 'long string'` is the same string as `Example long string`.

Comment: Also note that `sales_file.write(…+'\n')` is more simply written as `print >> sales_file, …`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are closing the file inside the for-loop. Next time through the loop when you write to the file, you are trying to write to a file that has been closed, hence the error message that says `I/O operation on closed file.`.

Move the line

```
sales_file.close()
```

to after the print statement at the bottom of the for-loop, but indent it at the level of the `for`. That will close the file only *once* after the loop (rather than repeatedly), i.e., when you are done with it at the end of your program.

Like this:

```
for count in range(1, num_days + 1):
   sales = float(input('Enter the sales for day #' + str(count) + ': '))
   sales_file.write(str(sales) + '\n')
   print('Data written to sales.txt.')

sales_file.close()   # close file once when done
```

A better approach would be to use the `with` statement as it will automatically close the file for you when you are done. So you could say

```
with open('sales.txt', 'w') as sales_file:
   for count in range(1, num_days + 1)
      # rest of the code
      # but *no* close statement needed.
```

Comment: @user1291271 Glad it worked for you! You should accept Levon's answer with the green checkmark now: it rewards both of you with reputation and marks this question as solved, so more people don't keep coming to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a cleaner way if you used `with open('sales_file','w')` 
that way once you leave the `with` block it will automatically close the
file. So you would edit your function to read:

```
def main():

    num_days = int(input('For how many days do ' + \
                        'you have sales? '))

    with open('sales.txt', 'w') as sales_file:
        for count in range(1, num_days + 1):
            sales = float(input('Enter the sales for day #' + \
                                str(count) + ': '))
            sales_file.write(str(sales) + '\n')
            print('Data written to sales.txt.')
    # once you leave the block (here) it automatically closes sales_file
main()
```

Comment: Cool, definitely look to use that in the future

Answer (score 0):

You close the file in 1 loop and then write to it in the next iteration.  Put close outside of the loop

```
def main():

     num_days = int(input('For how many days do ' + \
                          'you have sales? '))

     sales_file = open('sales.txt', 'w')


     for count in range(1, num_days + 1):
         sales = float(input('Enter the sales for day #' + \
                             str(count) + ': '))
         sales_file.write(str(sales) + '\n')
         print('Data written to sales.txt.')

     sales_file.close()

main()
```

Even better, you can use `with`

```
def main():

     num_days = int(input('For how many days do you have sales? '))

     with open('sales.txt', 'w') as sales_file:

         for count in range(1, num_days + 1):
             sales = input('Enter the sales for day #%s: ' % count)
             sales_file.write('%s\n' % sales)
             print('Data written to sales.txt.')

main()
```